# What are the security implications of making a clientaccesspolicy proxy workaround?

Tags: silverlight, security, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I wanted to use **published GoogleDocs documents** and **twitter tweets** as the datasource of a Silverlight application but ran into **clientaccesspolicy** issues.

I read many **articles** like [this](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/03/use-silverlight-with-any-feed-without-cross-domain-files.aspx) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/12/12/silverlight-crossdomain-access-workarounds.aspx) about how difficult it is to get around the **clientaccesspolicy** issue.

So I wrote this **CURL script** and put it on my PHP site and now I can get the text of any GoogleDocs document and twitter feed into my **Silverlight** application:

```
<?php
$url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$validUrls[] = "http://docs.google.com";
$validUrls[] = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline"; 

if(beginsWithOneOfThese($url, $validUrls)) {
  $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
  echo curl_exec($ch);
} else
  echo "invalid url";

function beginsWithOneOfThese($main, $prefixes) {
  foreach($prefixes as $prefix) {
    if(beginsWith($main, $prefix))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function beginsWith($main, $prefix) {
    return strpos($main, $prefix) === 0;
}

?>
```

So it makes me wonder:

- Why is there **so much discussion** about whether or not URLs support clientaccesspolicy or not, since you just have to write a **simple proxy script** and get the information through it?
- Why aren't there **services**, e.g. like the URL shortening services, which **supply** this functionality?
- What are the **security implications** of having a script like this?

Answer (score 2):

While you might think that a proxy gives you the same capabilities as having the client make the request, it doesn't. More specifically, you won't have the client's cookies/credentials for the target site, and in some cases, a client can reach the target site but your proxy can't (e.g. Intranet).

http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/Explaining-Same-Origin-Policy-Part-1-Deny-Read.aspx explains Same Origin Policy at some length.

In terms of the security implications for your proxy-- well, that depends on whether you have access control on that. If not, a bad guy could use your proxy to hide his tracks as he hacks sites or downloads illegal content.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, e.g. I did run into an issue that it couldn't follow redirected sites, but it seems I have access to any open text document on the open Internet, e.g. all RSS feeds, published Google Docs, any public website.

Comment: are there any public services which provide this functionality? I would think it would be valuable to collect the URLs that are being accessed in a similar way they are collected by URL shortening services, and then all the security could be concentrated in one point

Comment: ok, I added URL access control to it as you suggested, good point.